# Javascript Object.entries()

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to ask is there any way I can get first entry of *Object.entries()*. I am stil new to ***Object*** and for some reason, I want to show from second row onwards only. Thanks in advance!

Code below show all entries which is not what I want.

```
for (let i=0; i<row.length; i++) {
    for(let pair of row[i].entries()){
        console.log(pair[0],pair[1]); //I want to hide this entry, and show the rest of the entries
    }
}
```

Comment: Second row or second entry of every row?

Answer (score 0):

Simply start from index 1.

```
for (let i=1; i<row.length; i++) {
    for(let pair of row[i].entries()){
        console.log(pair[0],pair[1]); //I want to hide this entry, and show the rest of the entries
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) the right way. It is a 'static' method of `Object`. Its result is an array of key value pairs, so if you need the entries starting from the second entry, you can just slice it. Keep in mind that the order of key value pairs may not be what you expect.

```js
const obj = {
  hi: "there",
  hello: "world",
};

for(let pair of Object.entries(obj).slice(1)) {
  console.log(pair[0],pair[1]);
}
```

Comment: They are very probably using the correct `.entries()` method of whatever iterable they have in `row` though (and it's certainly not a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You could something like the following:

Reading:

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
var object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
var arr = Object.entries(object1);
console.log(arr.slice(1));  //Immutable
console.log(arr.shift());   //Mutable

console.log(arr);
//Both will give [[key,value],[key,value],..]
```